# How to use Google Cloud SQL for a Flask web application without using SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, flask, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

My app is a Flask web server that has a postgresql backend. Up to now, I have been running setting up the DB on the same compute engine the server is on. I am transitioning my database from the compute engine to a dedicated DB server through Google Cloud SQL. My flask web app would ideally be running on Google Cloud Run.

I have been having trouble finding any instructions on the web with regards to setting up a connection using psycopg2 only, without using SQLAlchemy. My app isn't built using SQLAlchemy and would hate to have to transition it over if there is a simple solution to my problem.

I have tried the below but have not been able to connect to the database at all:

```
connectionString = 'dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s' % (db_name, db_username, user_pwd, public_IP)
conn = psycopg2.connect(connectionString)
```

or

```
connectionString = 'dbname=%s user=%s password=%s host=%s' % (db_name, db_username, user_pwd, '/cloudsql/{}'.format("my-project-id:us-central1:my-db-name"))
conn = psycopg2.connect(connectionString)
```

Neither case was able to connect to Cloud SQL. The code where I use the public IP would seemingly load for a while but wouldn't connect.

Is this possible to do with Cloud SQL? If not are there any alternatives that would allow this to be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What are the error messages?

Comment: The error message on the server says the connection timed out when I put the IP address. Nothing shows up on the cloud SQL logs.

Comment: The connection string is correct. As @JohnHanley commented this looks like a firewall issue.

Comment: In the logs do you see any error message regarding that the connection attempt to the DB failed? Can you share it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second example you showed will work for connecting as long as you have the [Cloud SQL Proxy deployed via Unix socket](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-auth-proxy#unix-sockets).

To test it the application locally you would install the Proxy and then run the following:

```
./cloud-sql-proxy --unix-socket /cloudsql <PROJECT_ID>:<INSTANCE_REGION>:<INSTANCE_NAME> &
```

To run the Cloud SQL Proxy with Cloud Run you can use the `--add-cloudsql-instances` if you are deploying via gcloud:

```
gcloud run deploy <SERVICE_NAME> \
  --add-cloudsql-instances <PROJECT_ID>:<INSTANCE_REGION>:<INSTANCE_NAME>
```

Otherwise if you are using the Cloud Console you can just add a "Cloud SQL Connection" to your Cloud Run service and the Unix socket connection should work.